# I want to read android play store app rating in my android app

Tags: android, google-play

I want to read app rating from android play store of my app. To do this, is there any api provided by google or not?

Is there any other way to read rating of particular app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/), as this is the unofficial API, i am not sure it will work fully.

To fetch Rating of a particular app, try [HowToSearchApps](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps) from the same API.

Comment: Thanks Paresh, Giving me this type of error : 

"The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Shall i have to add another library?

Comment: Hi Bipin Vayalu: I am getting the same error, did u resolved this?